# Como escrever um post de um array no indice atual - input file

Tags: php, array, post

Seguinte pessoal, estou adaptando um sistema de upload de arquivos para php. Todo o grosso já foi criado, insert e update e tal, porém no meio da lógica precisando de uma condicional para checar se o campo input file foi usado, se estiver vazio não fazer nada, se estiver preenchido fazer o update. Tenho a solução parcial que me passaram que foi esta:

```
if ($_POST['file'] != '') {
 UPDATE
}
```

Porém estou usando php e o campo upload vem de um array da seguinte maneira

```
<input type="file" id="file1" name="file1[]"></input>
```

Como faço para escrever este if considerando o laço atual ?

O meu código do laço hoje está assim:

```
if($numFile <= 0){ //Laço que vai servir pra checar se o input está vazio
    echo 'Selecione uma Imagem!';
}else{
for($i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++){
    $name   = $file['name'][$i];
    $type   = $file['type'][$i];
    $size   = $file['size'][$i];
    $error  = $file['error'][$i];
    $tmp    = $file['tmp_name'][$i];  .... e o programa segue
```

Eu precisava de alguma maneira checar se o input está vazio, se estiver jogo o valor no $numFile dai faço o Update ou não, todo o resto do programa está funcionando, já com imagens em banco e tudo. O problema é que sem está condicional, independente de já ter uma imagem upada, se eu clicar em upload sem enviar foto ela vai sobrescrever meu banco com espaço em branco

Answer (score 1):

Teste assim:

```
$file= $_FILES['file1'];   // trate este valor como uma array
foreach( $file as $esteFile ) {
  if( $esteFile != '') {
     // UPDATE
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, Testando...

Comment: Teste mas não deu certo, pra simplificar usei assim:
<pre>
    $file2= $_FILES['file1'];   // trate este valor como uma array
    foreach( $file2 as $esteFile ) {
       if( $esteFile != '') {
       $numFile = 0;
       }
    }
</pre>  

    if($numFile <= 0){
      echo 'Selecione uma Imagem!';
    }else{

Comment: Perdão pela formatação, ainda estou aprendendo a usar o stackoverflow, sou marinheiro de primeiro viagem.

Answer (score 0):

Para verificar se existe algum upload(arquivo), vc de utilizar `$_FILES` e não `$_POST`.

```
if (isset($_FILES['file1']) && $_FILES['file1'] != ''){
   //update
}
```

Comment: Testando ... obrigado

Comment: Qual o problema da resposta @downvoter?

Comment: O que tem eu? você @perdeu meu marcou no comentário

Comment: @downvoter, qual comentário? em qual pergunta?

Comment: Agora nessa resposta... você colocou @downvoter que sou eu

Comment: Tem razão em usar `$_FILES` +1.

Comment: @perdeu quando você disse "Qual o problema da resposta @downvoter"

Comment: Parece que foi um engano, @downvoter, seu nick antes não era userAlgumNumero?

Comment: Não @perdeu , sempre foi downvoter! mas blz foi um mal entendido.

Comment: @perdeu ou melhor foi uma **falha no engano**

Comment: Não funcionou, seguirei amanhã na guerra com PHP. Obrigado pela força

Answer (score 0):

creio que por se tratar de um array voce deva validar como tal.

note que seu input esta assim

```
    ""
```

o ideial ja seria ele estar com os numeros definidos, tipo:

```
// entao se testaria mais ou menos assim...

for($i=1;$total;$i++){

   if( $file['error'][$i] == 0){
     echo 'este veio com erro!';
   } else{

    // continua o upload

   }
}
```

creio que seja isso